# Can i configure pytest to ignore directories when it's running with --looponfail option?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a directory with a unittest-module and a `logs`-directory where debug-informations are written.
since I use the `-f` / `--looponfail` option, I need changes in the `logs`-directory to be ignored.

```
tests$ ls
logs  __pycache__  pytest.ini  test_basic.py

tests$ cat pytest.ini
[pytest]
norecursedirs = logs
python_files = test_*.py

tests$ py.test -h
(...)
[pytest] ini-options in the next pytest.ini|tox.ini|setup.cfg file:

  markers (linelist)       markers for test functions
  norecursedirs (args)     directory patterns to avoid for recursion
  usefixtures (args)       list of default fixtures to be used with this project
  python_files (args)      glob-style file patterns for Python test module discovery
  python_classes (args)    prefixes for Python test class discovery
  python_functions (args)  prefixes for Python test function and method discovery
  addopts (args)           extra command line options
  minversion (string)      minimally required pytest version
  rsyncdirs (pathlist)     list of (relative) paths to be rsynced for remote distributed testing.
  rsyncignore (pathlist)   list of (relative) glob-style paths to be ignored for rsyncing.
  looponfailroots (pathlist) directories to check for changes
```

Eventually the failing test is invoked in a loop, because changes in `logs/test_basic.log` are monitored and I wonder why this is so.  The [documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/customize.html) seems clear to me.

Comment: I have a similar situation. Maybe when testing, you just have to turn off logging. Did you find a solution to 'unwatch' a directory?

Answer (score 4):

`looponfailroots` now solves this problem. Put this in your `setup.cfg`:

```
[tool:pytest]
looponfailroots=mylib
```

Comment: This specifies a folder or a list of folders, but does not support skipping folder or pattern. Also not documented [yet](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/499)

Answer (score 1):

pytest-xdist has no option that influences what files are ignored on `--looponfail`. The `norecursedirs` only influences what files are collected as tests.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

1) I expected that the settings in my `pytest.ini` are reflected in the output of `py.test -h`. Is that a false assumption?

2) Are there plans to change the behaviour of the fs-monitoring towards a way I assumed it? Otherwise, would there be a reason to stop me trying to figure that out?

Comment: feel free to work on a PR on pytest-xdist which introduces an ini-variable specifying watch patterns.

Answer (score 1):

As @hpk42 points out the `norecursedirs` only affects test-collection, not filesystem-monitoring.

So, a possibility to deal with it is to move the logs out of the test-directory.